# How to add objects to a different model when using a form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-3.0

I have a few forms that retrieve objects through a ForeignKey, e.g. `Flight`, `Trip`.

So, for example, when someone tries to create a new `Trip`, they can choose an `Hotel` from a dropdown.

My question is: how can we, on the `Trip` form, add an `Hotel`. Just like when using Django's own admin dashboard, where you get a plus sign, and you can add a new `Hotel` while creating a `Trip`.

Edit:

`Hotel` is a ForeignKey on the `Trip` model.
And I am using `ModelForm`.

The objective is that you can either choose an existing `Hotel` or create a new one while creating a `Trip`.

Comment: is `Hotel` a FK on the `Trip` model? And are you using model forms or regular forms?

Comment: @DeA yes, `Hotel` is a FK on `Trip`. I am using model Forms.

Comment: Have a read through this & then see if you can get a solution that works for you; https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-use-nested-formsets-in-django/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `forms.ModelChoiceField`.
It is used this way:

```
hotel = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Hotel.objects.all() # or whatever queryset you want to use
    # Rest of the configuration
)
```

If I'm not mistaken, it will create an Html `Select` tag having options with `pk` of each `Hotel` object as the value. To specify the inner text of each option, you have to define the following method for the `Hotel` class:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name # or whatever needed
```

If you indeed were looking for this I have to discourage you from using it if you are building a production-grade website/app. A better (and obviously more elaborate) approach is to get the query set of `Hotels`, serialize them to JSON, create a card/row/widget for each hotel for the user to search and select. However, it is a quick and handy way of managing small projects.

Comment: I think the question is actually, how can a `Hotel` object be created from a page where a `Trip` object is created. So you render a `Trip` `ModelForm` to a page and have an ability to create a `Hotel` from the same page.

Comment: @markwalker you're right. I want the ability to either choose an existing `Hotel` or creating a new one. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @JoãodeSousa Sorry, did not understand the question correctly